# @RestController password encrytion and sending data in json with hibernate

Tags: angularjs, spring, hibernate

I create a login/registration form in angularjs and use spring boot. When i register a user i use following code to send the data to the database:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/register",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public User addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        LOGGER.info("Received request to create the {}", user);
        return repo.saveAndFlush(user);
    }
```

How can i encrypt the password into the database ?

Then i also want to create something similar for the login.
But how do i get the stuff  back from the server in json format to angularjs.
Is this secure. And how to handle a password encryption?
Is it also possible to hide the password while validating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally we don't encrypt a password but we hash it, so that it is not possible to get back the password. When a user tries to connect to the application you need to hash his password and compare it with the hashed one stored in database.

I'm using [spring security BCrypt password encoder](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html) to hash. It is very simple to use.

You can find a large amount of examples about how to hash a password in java. here is an [example](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/07/22/how-to-generate-secure-password-hash-md5-sha-pbkdf2-bcrypt-examples/).

In order to return a User in Json format to client, you need just to add this annotation : @ResponseBody (Spring MVC uses Jackson to convert it to Json format).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody User addUser(@RequestBody User user) {

    .....

    return user
}
```